# print関数を使用したら思うように実行されずSyntaxError: invalid syntaxといエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: python

print関数を使用したら思うように実行されずSyntaxError: invalid syntaxといエラーが出てしまいます。

[image: これです]

Comment: その直前の行に閉じ括弧`)`が無いからでは？

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキスト（マークダウン）で記入しましょう。

Answer (score 2):

google colaboratory環境だからエラーの発生状況が変わってしまっていて分かりにくくなっているようですね。(実際にはその環境で使われているPython版数が原因のようです。→追記参照)
コメントに書いたようにgoogle colaboratoryでSyntaxErrorと指摘された行ではなく、その直前の行の閉じ括弧`)`が無いために発生しています。

問題が再現する最小な部分にまで短縮するとこんなコードになります。

```
mein_card="恐竜"
print("あなたはB-userです。あなたのキャラクターは"
print(mein_card)
```

google colaboratory環境で見える形をテキストで再現するとこのようなエラー表示になりますが：

```
mein_card="恐竜"
print("あなたはB-userです。あなたのキャラクターは"
print(mein_card)
```

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-9a888d9a61f2>", line 3
    print(mein_card)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`SEARCH STACK OVERFLOW`

---

ローカルPCのコマンドプロンプトではこんな形になって問題の部分を直接指摘してくれます。

```
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> mein_card="恐竜"
>>> print("あなたはB-userです。あなたのキャラクターは"
... print(mein_card)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("あなたはB-userです。あなたのキャラクターは"
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
>>>
```

google colaboratory環境はそういう問題の箇所とはズレたところでエラーを表示する場合があると認識して、エラーの周辺にも問題が無いか気を付けてみてください。

---

**追記**

@mjy さんの指摘で、google colaboratory環境だからでは無くPython版数の違いが原因のようですね。

現在のgoogle colaboratoryのPythonは3.7.13です。

試しにローカルPCのコマンドプロンプトにPythonは3.9.13の環境で実行してみたら、質問と同様のエラーになりました。

それで[What’s New In Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html)を調べてみたら以下の項目が該当するようです。
[Better error messages](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#better-error-messages)

つまり注意する内容は変わりませんが、google colaboratory環境にかかわらず、Python 3.10系未満ならばすべて該当していて注意する必要があるということになります。

Comment: エラーメッセージの違いは、Python のバージョンの違いによるもののようです。3.7.13 だと、ローカルの repl でも同じエラーメッセージが出ました。

Comment: なるほど、そんなこともあるんですか。それなら、そういうことも含めてなるべく最新の版数を使ってみた(あるいは両方で試すとかした)方が良いようですね。